# Spring batch integration test using jobLauncherTestUtils

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to write an integration test of my batch project.

My integration test definition:

https://github.com/cristianprofile/spring-batch-testing/blob/master/src/test/java/test/BatchApplicationTests.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest

/* @Autowired
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;*/

public class BatchApplicationTests {

private static final String EXPECTED_FILE = "src/test/resources/users.csv";
private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "src/main/resources//users.csv";
private static final String EXPECTED_FILE2 = "src/test/resources/users2.csv";
private static final String OUTPUT_FILE2 = "src/main/resources//users2.csv";

@Test
public void contextLoads()  throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Fake test ");
//      JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
//        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("step1");
//      Assert.assertEquals("COMPLETED",    jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
//
//
//       AssertFile.assertFileEquals(new FileSystemResource(EXPECTED_FILE),
//                new FileSystemResource(OUTPUT_FILE));
//
//        AssertFile.assertFileEquals(new FileSystemResource(EXPECTED_FILE2),
//                new FileSystemResource(OUTPUT_FILE2));

}
```

Spring configuration test folder:

```
package test;

import com.mymoid.batch.configuration.BatchConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

 @SpringBootConfiguration
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @Import({BatchTestConfig.class, BatchConfiguration.class})
 public class TestServiceConfigIT {
 }
```

BatchTestConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchTestConfig {

@Bean
JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
    return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
}

}
```

BatchConfiguration.class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader(){
    JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<User>();
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setSql("SELECT id,name FROM user");
    reader.setRowMapper(new UserRowMapper());
    return reader;
}



@Bean
public UserItemProcessor processor(){
    return new UserItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer(){
    FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<User>();

    final FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource("/Users/mymoid/projects/batch/src/main" +
            "/resources/users.csv");

    FlatFileHeaderCallback prueba= new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
        @Override
        public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
            writer.write("columna1,cloumna2");
        }
    };
    writer.setHeaderCallback(prueba);
    writer.setResource(fileSystemResource);
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<User>() {{
        setDelimiter(",");
        setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>() {{
            setNames(new String[] { "address.id", "address.name" });
        }});
    }});

    return writer;
}


@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer2(){
    FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<User>();
    final FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource("/Users/mymoid/projects/batch/src/main" +
            "/resources/users2.csv");

    FlatFileHeaderCallback prueba= new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
        @Override
        public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
            writer.write("columna1");
        }
    };
    writer.setHeaderCallback(prueba);
    writer.setResource(fileSystemResource);
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<User>() {{
        setDelimiter(",");
        setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>() {{
            setNames(new String[] { "id"});
        }});
    }});

    return writer;
}




@Bean
public CompositeItemWriter compositeItemWritercomposite(){
    FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<User>();
    writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("users2.csv"));
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<User>() {{
        setDelimiter(",");
        setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>() {{
            setNames(new String[] { "id"});
        }});
    }});

    final FlatFileItemWriter writer1 = writer();
    final FlatFileItemWriter<User>  userFlatFileItemWriter = writer2();
    List<ItemWriter<User>> writers = new ArrayList<>(2);
    writers.add(writer1);
    writers.add(userFlatFileItemWriter);
    CompositeItemWriter itemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter();

    itemWriter.setDelegates(writers);
    return itemWriter;
}


@Bean OrderWriter orderWriter()
{
   return new OrderWriter();
}







@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<User, User> chunk(2)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(compositeItemWritercomposite())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job exportUserJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step1())
            .end()
            .build();
}

}
```

When i run contextLoads (test case is empty) Spring runs the same way that when i run my main program. Why Spring runs batch if every lines of my code are commented?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the `SpringBootTest` annotation's [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html):

> Automatically searches for a @SpringBootConfiguration when nested @Configuration is not used, and no explicit classes are specified.

In your test class, you did not use `@contextConfiguration` or specify which classes to load the application context from. So Spring Boot automatically searches for Spring boot configurations, it finds you batch job configuration and runs it.

You can disable this by adding `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` to your `application.properties` file.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have deleted @contextConfiguration class and Test works like a charm!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

I have just fixed this problem putting  false value to this application.properties (inside test resources) value:

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

See Complete application properties file here:
https://github.com/cristianprofile/spring-batch-testing/blob/master/src/test/resources/application.properties